# I cant get my prototypes in my constructors to be responsive

Tags: javascript

I have three constructors. School, Teachers, and Students.
So far everything in my code feels okay but I cannot seem to get two functions within the teacher.prototype to respond. I am new to Js and am trying to learn on why this isn't responsive

```
//create a constructor for a school that has all teachers and students
function school(principal,teacher,student,classroom,detention){
    this.principal = principal,
    this.teacher = teacher,
    this.student = student;
    this.classroom = [],
    this.detention = []
}
//create a constructor for teachers and students 
//link them all together
function teacher(admin,name){
    this.admin = admin
    this.name = name
    admin = true
//inherit some of the properties of school

}
function student(fname,lname,year,average){
    this.fname = fname,
    this.lname = lname,
    this.year = year,
    this.average = average
}
teacher.prototype = Object.create(school.prototype);
//teacher can send students to class
teacher.prototype.learn = function(student){
    this.classroom.unshift(student)
}
//be able to move students to detention
teacher.prototype.punish = function(student){
    this.detention.unshift(student)
} 


student.prototype = Object.create(teacher.prototype)
student.prototype.fullDetails = function(){
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname + " is in " + this.year + 'th' + ' grade and his average is ' + this.average;
}


var mr_feeney = new teacher(true,"Mr.Feeney")
var corey = new student("corey","mathews",10,88)
var shaun = new student("shaun","hunter",10,43)
var top = new student("topanga","lawrence",10,43)

shaun.learn();
```

Comment: how are you initializing school ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructors of classes that are **inheriting** prototypes, you need to call the constructor of what you are inheriting from, in the context of your current object.

e.g. in your student constructor you need to do this

```
function student(fname,lname,year,average){
    //initialize all the member variables on this object that are created in the teacher constructor by calling teacher.call(this)
    teacher.call(this); 

    this.fname = fname,
    this.lname = lname,
    this.year = year,
    this.average = average
}
```

which calls the teacher constructor and initializes all the member variables that are ***inherited*** from teacher.

This is the same with `teacher` that inherits from `school`

```
function teacher(admin,name){
    school.call(this);
    this.admin = admin
    this.name = name
    admin = true
}

teacher.prototype = Object.create(school.prototype);
```

Also, stick with convention, use uppercase for your class names

```
function student()
```

should be

```
function Student()
```

All this being said, you've got some other architectural oddness going on - should a student really inherit all the same methods as a teacher? Should a teacher really inherit all the same properties/methods as a school? What should the default arguments of admin and name be when you call the teacher constructor from the student constructor?

Comment: thank you for your help. I just started object oriented js in class and this was one of the assignments to have the teacher can change the classroom of a student, give detention to a student, etc